# Limiting the output range of tagged words

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I want to extract all the names(first,middle,last) in a document and show the first two complete names separately.

I've already tried a nested for loop and all , but I could not figure it out.

```
for result in classified_text:
    tag_value= result[0],
    tag_name= result[1]
    if tag_name=='PERSON':
           print(''.join([tup for tup in tag_value]))
```

Expected results :

```
Steven.K.Lamberson

Steve.I.Blanton
```

Actual Results :

```
Briazz
Steven
K.
Lamberson
Steve
I.
Blanton
Briazz
Briazz
Proto
Briazz
Moulder
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Cess
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
Briazz
```

Comment: can you show an exemple of how you get the input (ie ```classified_text```) ?

Comment: classified_text = [ ('referred', 'O'), ('to', 'O'), ('as', 'O'),('or', 'O'), ('meaning', 'O'), ('thereof', 'O'),('Part', 'O'), (',', 'O'), ('AND', 'O'), ('Briazz', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('company', 'O'), ('incorporated', 'O'), ('under', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('provisions', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('Companies', 'O'), ('Act', 'O'), (',', 'O'), ('1956', 'O'), (',', 'O'), ('having', 'O'), ('its', 'O'), ('registered', 'O'), ('place', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('business', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('2731', 'O'), ('Crestview', 'LOCATION')]

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import re

person=''
last_tag=''
for result in classified_text:
    tag_value= result[0],
    tag_name= result[1]
    if tag_name=='PERSON':
        if last_tag == 'PERSON':
           person += ' ' + tag_value
        else:
           person = tag_value
    else if last_tag == 'PERSON' and re.match('\w+\ \w+\. \w+', person):
           print(person)
    last_tag = tag_value
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @godot , but i'm not getting any output from the above code..